# Handling button click and button touch simultaneously in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, button, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

Here is some seemingly classical code, that I have in a small android app.
It is handling some button, so nothing special going on; but this is the question:

This code work as long as I choose to have one of the two function blocks
*theBtn.setOnClickListener {..}* or *theBtn.setOnTouchListener {..}*.

But it no longer works if I want to have both at the same time. Am I missing some thing ?

```
    val greyLvl = 0x89
    val stdColor = Color.rgb(greyLvl,greyLvl,greyLvl)
    val hiLiColor = Color.rgb(0x33,0x66,0x88)

    val theBtn = Button(this)
    theBtn.setTextColor(stdColor)
    theBtn.setBackgroundColor(0x00)
    theBtn.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 31.dpToPixels(this))
    theBtn.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)
    theBtn.text = "THE BUTTON"


    theBtn.setOnClickListener {
        // Handling the button action.
        println("-- theBtn.setOnClickListener --")
    }


    theBtn.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
        // Controlling the button color.
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            theBtn.setTextColor(hiLiColor)
        } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            theBtn.setTextColor(stdColor)
        }

        return@setOnTouchListener true;
    }


    scrolVwLayOut.addView(theBtn)
```

Comment: *Am I missing some thing ?* yeah ... what means returned value in listener

Comment: So what should I change? My experience in Android development is very limited.

Comment: "on click" is based on "on touch". if you return true in "on touch" then you it cannot be interpreted as "on click" ... so returning false should do the trick ... **but ... better is no to use on touch at all if all you wana do is to change the color of the button itself ... you may use style to do this** ... you may use [ColorStateList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList) for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because onTouch and onClick will conflict，When you consume the event in onTouchListener, that is  `return@setOnTouchListener true;` will not execute the click again, if you want the click event to be executed after `ACTION_UP`, just `return@setOnTouchListener false`

Like Selvin said, if you just want to change the color or background of the button when pressed, you shouldn't do it this way,use drawable selector is the best!

Comment: Indeed using: "return@setOnTouchListener true;" makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you reused the same button for two different listeners. I am not too experienced, but how would you get it to do two different actions at the same time? maybe use a when statement for motion and then call the touch listener, else use onClick? Sorry if that doesn't work. Let me know though please! Also curious :)

Comment: per my answer, I want to clarify, you have no logic in your blocks, you need something to tie them together, it will likely use the first block in the activity. So that's why you should encase them in if/else or when statements.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).